# AWS Amplify Android Studios accessing data from DynamoDB via Api Gateway RestEndpoint

Tags: android, rest, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-api-gateway

Currently, using AWS Amplify with Android Studio (Java) to create an application that can display data from the dynamo DB table as it is populated with IoT devices.

Currently using the following within Amplify on the backend

- -> Storage: DynamoDB -> Data is stored and populated here
- -> API : REST API -> API Gateway Service
- -> Function : Lambda -> connected to the DynamoDB Table to do CRUD operations

I am able to retrieve data by using the REST endpoint
"https://xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev"

with using the addition of this path: "/items/{epoch}"

I have done the following to attempt to extract the data object from the Rest Response within the Amplify.API.get() method. As an attempt to get my data from dynamo DB (See Below):

```
ArrayList<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();

void getItems(String epoch) {

        RestOptions options = RestOptions.builder()
                .addPath("/items/" + epoch)
                .build();

        RestOperation operation = Amplify.API.get(options,
                restResponse ->
                {
                    String rawData = restResponse.getData().asString();
                    ls.add(rawData);
                    Log.i("RESTapiOperation", "GET succeeded: " + restResponse.getData().asString());
                },
                apiFailure ->
                        Log.e("RESTapiOperation", "GET failed: ", apiFailure)
        );
        Log.i("Data Collection", "Size of list is " + ls.size());
```

I keep getting the list being at size 0, even though I attempt to add the RESTresponse to the list. Other methods tried had to do with the DynamoDBClient methods from android Mobile SDK that are depreciated and no longer being supported by AWS teams. I am unsure how to extract data from dynamo DB and display it for the mobile user.

Any suggestions/tips would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any solution?